# How to deep clone this part of javascript?

Tags: javascript

still very new in js overall and i'm trying to deep clone this part of code.

```
$scope.add = function() {
  $scope.data.push(Object.assign(mock));
};
```

If anyone could help me cloning this, would be grateful. Thanks

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The problem is if I add this item two times, then the content is duplicated from one to another. Did some research that deep cloning might fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use angular's **[`.copy()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)** method to clone.

like this

```
$scope.data.push(angular.copy(mock));
```

Comment: Wow, works as intended. Spent a lot of time on that and it just took one minute for you. Thanks a lot. (need to wait 7 more minutes that I could mark your answer)

Comment: @Frutis you are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an actual clone where changes to the clone don't effect the object you are cloning:

```or-tag-here
Object.assign({}, mock)
```

Comment: Anik already answered my question with a working example, but I have tried your solution and it works also, just not sure if there is a huge difference in using one of the codes.

Comment: This performs a shallow copy though, not a deep copy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, another way to deep copy is by using `.extend(true, target, object1 [, objectN ] )`

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/